# How to pass a value between stages in a pipeline returned by invoking a PowerShell script?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline:

```
stages:
  - stage: Stage1
    jobs:
      - job: RunScript
        steps:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              pwsh: true
              targetType: 'filePath'
              filePath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/scripts/myscript1.ps1
  - stage: Stage2
    jobs:
      - job: RunScript
        steps:
          - task: PowerShell@2
            inputs:
              pwsh: true
              targetType: 'filePath'
              filePath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/scripts/myscript1.ps1
              arguments: >
                -Arg ??? # <======= HERE
```

`Stage1` runs `myscript1.ps1` which is (for simplicity):

```
$OutputValue = 'Hello'
$OutputValue
```

It is just a script which will eventually return something.

#### The problem

The issue is that the value produced by `myscript1.ps1` in `Stage1` must be consumed by `myscript2.ps1` in `Stage2`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [output variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable) as here

With the script `myscript1.ps1` as this:

```
echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myOutputVar;isOutput=true]this is the value"
```

and pipeline:

```yaml
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
     - task: PowerShell@2
       inputs:
         pwsh: true
         targetType: 'filePath'
         filePath: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/scripts/myscript1.ps1
       name: setvarStep

- stage: B
  dependsOn: A
  variables:
    myVarfromStageA: $[ stageDependencies.A.A1.outputs['setvarStep.myOutputVar'] ]
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    steps:
    - script: echo $(myVarfromStageA)
```

You can retrive value in the next stage.

It doesn't matter if you use it inside the script file. But important here is to have step named as later you will use it to reference output variable created by it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think it would be better if you could please modify it by adding using my code and posting the script file code which has `echo ...` inside it. That will highlight the fact that the special syntax can be used inside scripts too.